# Does No-cloning theorem hold in time domain?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

So for an unknown quantum state $|A\rangle$, it's impossible to make a copy of $|B\rangle$ such that $|A\rangle=|B\rangle$.

However, I want to know that, suppose the unknown $|A\rangle$ is time dependent, i.e. $|A(t)\rangle$ where an actual dependence in phase were presented, that $|A(t_0)\rangle\neq |A(t)\rangle$ for some $t\neq t_0$. Is it possible to "clone" the state $|B(t)\rangle$, such that $|A(t)\rangle=|B(t+\tau)\rangle$ where $\tau>0$ a positive real number.

That was, does non clone theorem hold in time domain? Is it possible to duplicate a $|B(t)\rangle$ that has a time difference with $|A(t)\rangle$?

**To make question more clear:**

No cloning theorem: There does not exists $C$ such that, if $|A\rangle$ was an unknown state, $C|A\rangle|0\rangle=|A\rangle|A\rangle$?

Question:
Does there exists $C$ such that $C|A(t)\rangle|0(t)\rangle=|A(t)\rangle|A(t-\tau)\rangle$, where $\tau>0$ a real number, $|A(t_1)\rangle\neq|A(t_2)\rangle$ for some $t_1\neq t_2$.

Additional comment: If possible, one may consider $|A(t)\rangle$ in three cases: 1. $|A(t_1)\rangle\neq|A(t_2)\rangle$ for all $t_1\neq t_2$. 2.  $|A(t_1)\rangle\neq|A(t_2)\rangle$ for some $t_1\neq t_2$. 3. $|A(t)\rangle$ is periodic. Also, please consider $\tau$ in two cases: 1. $\tau$ is known and fixed. 2. $\tau$ is unkonw.

Comment: As it is now the question is completely unclear.  Normal cloning takes an arbitary state $|A\rangle$ and maps it to two copies: $C|A\rangle = |A\rangle|A\rangle$.  How would the action of your cloner look like?

Comment: But what is the meaning of a map which maps *into* two different times?  Or do you want the map to act *at* a given time, and produce the state + a copy of what is was earlier?  If yes, how could we do this without knowledge of the Hamiltonian/unitary under which evolves - in that case it could be any state!  You ***have*** to be more specific in your question!

Comment: This is still quite unclear.   Is your equation supposed to hold for some $t$ or for all $t$?  Is $\tau$ allowed to depend on the initial state of the second particle?  Etc.

Comment: The way it stands now your question is completely unclear.  You should edit it to make it more precise.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I have reedited the question.

Comment: @WillO I was thinking that $|A(t-\tau)\rangle$ was a "new" states in the present spacetime, and thus it's possible to make it happen. Basically, I'm adding an additional dimension and throw the uninterested parts into time, and obtain a "cloned" states in space with a difference in time.

Comment: The question is still unclear. What is known, and what isn't?  Is |A(t)> known?  Is the relation of |A(t)> and |A(t+tau)> known (i.e. the Hamiltonian, or whatever generates the evolution)?  Or is none of them known?  Without this information, there is no clear answer!

Comment: To summarize:  You need to quantify (at least) over the Hamiltonian, the initial state of the second particle, the value of $\tau$, the value of $t$, the initial state $A(0)$ ...  A proper question would include several instances of the phrases "for all" and/or "there exists" (or the equivalents thereof).

Comment: Please do not add summaries of answers into the question. Questions should contain a *question* and nothing else.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thank you. The comment wasn't part of the answer or proof. But I made a pretty ridiculous mistake, just want to clear it up so that people won't get misleaded when read the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The no cloning theorem states that if you have two systems, $A$ and $B$, and the following state

$$|\psi\rangle_A|0\rangle_B $$

then there is no unitary $U$ such that

$$U|\psi\rangle_A|0\rangle_B=e^{i\alpha}|\psi\rangle_A|\psi\rangle_B $$

what you're asking, if I understand correctly, is whether there exists a unitary $U_\tau$ such that

$$U_\tau|\psi(t)\rangle_A|0\rangle_B=e^{i\alpha}|\psi(t)\rangle_A|\psi(t-\tau)\rangle_B $$

we can safely drop the $t$ and just notice that if $V(t)$ is the time evolution operator for $\psi$ then $|\psi(t-\tau)\rangle=V^\dagger(\tau)|\psi(t)\rangle$ .

So we're asking if there exist a unitary $U_\tau$ such that

$$U_\tau|\psi\rangle_A|0\rangle_B=e^{i\alpha}|\psi\rangle_A V^\dagger|\psi\rangle_B =e^{i\alpha}(\mathbb{1}\otimes V^\dagger) |\psi\rangle_A|\psi\rangle_B$$

but then

$$W=(\mathbb{1}\otimes V) U_\tau $$

is a unitary such that

$$W|\psi\rangle_A|0\rangle_B=e^{i\alpha}|\psi\rangle_A|\psi\rangle_B $$

but $W$ cannot exist due to the no cloning theorem, hence we arrived at a contradiction. Thus $U_\tau$ cannot exist.

Comment: Thank you, however, the proof was not complete. Suppose $\tau$ was known: Is it possible for the existence of $W$? Can $W$ actually exists? Because if $U_r$ exists, your proof stated that $W$ doesn't exist.       Suppose $\tau$ was not known( through the uncertainty): then we can make $W$ not exists or perhaps $W(\Delta \tau)$?

Comment: I don't really understand your point, what do you mean by known or not known?

Comment: You proved that "If $U_r$ exists, then $W$ does not exist." But you haven't prove that $U_r$ does not exist...

Comment: I proved that if $U_\tau$ exists, then $W$ exists, but $W$ cannot exist due to the no cloning theorem, contradiction. Thus $U_\tau$ cannot exist.

Comment: But how can you prove the existence of $W$? $V$ is the time operator you can't just make extra time. Further, $\tau$ may not be known thus $V(\tau)$ is not known and not exist.

Comment: I proved the existence of $W$ by providing an explicit expression for it, what do you mean by "you can't just make extra time"? If you have a state at time $0$ and you want the state at a time $\tau$, then you apply the time evolution operator $V(\tau)$.

Comment: I was thinking that in no cloning theorem, the space was $|a\rangle$ where $t$ was kind of special; but now the space is actually $|at\rangle$, I'm not sure weather one still have the freedom to make $(1\otimes V)$ in such system. But anyway I will ask another question about that. I'm doubting weather $(1\otimes V) $ is still a valid expression. Especially, if $\tau$ was unknow, $V$ does not exist.

Comment: If you're asking if a time evolution operator always exist, the answer is yes, because time evolution is linear and unitary (i.e. the solution of the Schroedinger equation doesn't change norm as it evolves in time), hence there always exists a unitary operator $V$ such that $|\psi(t_2)\rangle=V|\psi(t_1)\rangle$

Comment: @user9976437 I think you're confused about how time evolution works in quantum mechanics, the space in which states are defined doesn't change, the state at a given time is still in the same Hilbert space

Comment: Thank you. I got it. I was thinking about a process of strict synchronization, of which $(1\otimes V(t))$  could not exist. (flat space & cross section etc.) That's why I could not figure out where I went wrong(basically, one could not make use of both $\tau$ or $V(t)$ because of the uncertainty, thus it's impossible for one to make use of iteration to return to its original state based on probability). But I guess a round trip across gravity would prove it false if assuming the continuity of time.